# Ruby client for Monster job search/post API

Tags: ruby, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

I have been looking for some information on writing a ruby client (preferably using savon) for the Monster job search/post APIs.

Doc for reference - http://integrations.monster.com/doc

I was able to play around with the monster web service toolkit. I tried with soapUI and with savon to make a service call but I couldn't get it right. I am sure I am missing something here.

Did anyone try integrating monster job search (using web-services/apis) with ruby/rails applications? I would really appreciate any help, suggestions and comments on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I could at least call monster search web service using savon.

Here is the link to sample code -

https://github.com/shettigarc/s-sourcecode/blob/master/ruby/apic/monster_job_search_api.rb

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code you use to connect?

I am using [Savon](https://github.com/rubiii/savon) with some other services and found I needed to use a slightly older version (0.7.9), although I see 0.8.3 seems to be out now...

Are you using something to check whats going back and forth?  I find [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) very useful.

Comment: Chris, 
Thanks for responding. I was away busy last 2 days with some other stuff. I figured it out. I will reply with a sample code in a bit